# How to handle same component/functionality on multiple screens in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, zustand

I'm prompting a login modal on multiple screens in a Tab Navigation. After a successful/failed login, the modal code and the functionalities (create the session, sync the data, etc) after a successful/failed login need to be handled on those screens.

Initially, it's like the same code on multiple screens. So I'm refactoring it.

I want to know whether my approach is good. Are there any other refactorings that I can do to make it better?

**Current code**

Add all the functionalities and the modal component in each and every screen.

```
function DashboardScreen() {
    const [loginVisible, setLoginVisible] = useState(false);
    const [session, setSession] = useState(null);
    const [authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser] = useState(null);
    const [syncing, setSyncing] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(authenticatedUser){
      // create session
      setSession(session);
    }
  }, [authenticatedUser])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(session){
      setSyncing(true);
      // start sync process
      setSyncing(false);
    }
  }, [session])

    const handleLogin = () => {
        // authenticate with API
    setAuthenticatedUser(user);
    };

    return <LoginModal visible={loginVisible} handleLogin={handleLogin} loginClose={() => setLoginVisible(false)} />;
}

function ProductsScreen() {
    
  // same code as above

    return <LoginModal visible={loginVisible} handleLogin={handleLogin} loginClose={() => setLoginVisible(false)} />;
}
```

**My approach**

Add all states and actions to a store (Redux/Zustand) and keep the components clean.

```
function DashboardScreen() {
    // remove all actions and states from the screen level
    return <LoginModal />;
}

function ProductsScreen() {
    return <LoginModal />;
}

function LoginModal() {
    // get actions and state from the store
    const {loginVisible, setLoginVisible, handleLogin} = useStore();
}

const store = {
    loginVisible: false,
    session: null,
    authenticatedUser: null,
    syncing: false,
    setLoginVisible: () => {}, // function,
    setSession: () => {}, // function,
    setAuthenticatedUser: () => {}, // function,
    setSyncing: () => {}, // function,
    handleLogin: () => {}, // function,
};
```